# How to get the forward voltage of a tachometer?

Tags: tachometer

I am currently in the process of building a circuit board for components that I am going to use on a lathe. I want to use [this tachometer.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00VKAT8A2)

I have checked out the manufacturer website but it’s not in English, so I was wondering how I could find out the forward voltage on it, if I ordered it. I’d also like to state I would like to avoid a handheld tachometer if at all possible.

Comment: `I have checked out the manufacturer website` .... what might that be?

Comment: `I would like to avoid a handheld tach` .... what does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "forward voltage". That's a term usually used to describe the voltage drop over diodes.

The device you linked appears to be an all-in-one solution. You'll just need to power it using a wall wart between 8 and 15v. Anything > 300ma should be fine.

Here's a wiring diagram one of the reviewers made:

[image: Wiring diagram]